# Problem with deserialization of serialized object

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

few days ago I asked how to serialize controls (buttons, progressbar etc.) a lot of you suggested using DTO. Well seems like controls are bigger problem then I thought, how do i deserialize it? Serialization works fine and everything but deserialization kinda doesn't know which control to get what data, I used Name property but it doesn't work. Is there other property or something to fix this? Maybe I need JSON Serializer ?? thankss

```
public void Serialize()
{
    try
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream($"C:\\CapitalistGame\\SavedGame.sg", FileMode.Create);
        List<StoreDto> newListStoreDto = new List<StoreDto>();
        GameDto gameDto = new GameDto
        {
            Money = game.Money,
            Gold = game.Gold
        };
        game.Stores.ForEach(x =>
        {
            newListStoreDto.Add(new StoreDto
            {
                ProgressBar = new ProgressBarDto
                {
                    Name = x.ProgressBar.Name,
                    Value = x.ProgressBar.Value,
                    Minimum = x.ProgressBar.Minimum,
                    Maximum = x.ProgressBar.Maximum,
                },
                Button = new ButtonDto
                {
                    Text = x.UpgradeButton.Text,
                    Left = x.UpgradeButton.Left,
                    Top = x.UpgradeButton.Top,
                    Width = x.UpgradeButton.Width,
                    Height = x.UpgradeButton.Height,
                    Name = x.UpgradeButton.Name
                },
                Timer = new TimerDto
                {
                    Interval = x.Timer.Interval,
                    Enabled = x.Timer.Enabled
                },
                Label = new LabelDto
                {
                    Text = x.Label.Text,
                    Left = x.Label.Left,
                    Top = x.Label.Top,
                    Width = x.Label.Width,
                    Height = x.Label.Height,
                    Name = x.Label.Name
                },
                Label2 = new LabelDto
                {
                    Text = x.EarnLabel.Text,
                    Left = x.EarnLabel.Left,
                    Top = x.EarnLabel.Top,
                    Width = x.EarnLabel.Width,
                    Height = x.EarnLabel.Height,
                    Name = x.EarnLabel.Name
                },
                Name = x.Name,
                Interval = x.Interval,
                Num_Upgrades = x.Num_Upgrades,
                BaseCost = x.BaseCost,
                BaseMoney = x.BaseMoney,
                MoneyMaking = x.MoneyMaking,
                BaseInterval = x.BaseInterval,
                CostOfUpgrade = x.CostOfUpgrade,
                IntervalReducer = x.IntervalReducer,
                EarnMultiplier = x.EarnMultiplier,
                Clicked = x.Clicked,
                IsBought = x.IsBought,
                hasManager = x.hasManager,
                game = gameDto
            });
        });
        gameDto.Stores = newListStoreDto;
        formatter.Serialize(fileStream, gameDto);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("2");
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
private void Deserialize()
{

    if (File.Exists($"C:\\CapitalistGame\\SavedGame.sg"))
    {
        try
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream($"C:\\CapitalistGame\\SavedGame.sg", FileMode.Open);
            GameDto gameDto = (GameDto)formatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
            List<Store> newListStore = new List<Store>();
            game = new Game
            {
                Money = gameDto.Money,
                Gold = gameDto.Gold
            };
            gameDto.Stores.ForEach(x =>
            {
                ProgressBar pbd = new CustomProgressBar
                {
                    Name = x.ProgressBar.Name,
                    Value = x.ProgressBar.Value,
                    Minimum = x.ProgressBar.Minimum,
                    Maximum = x.ProgressBar.Maximum
                };
                Button bd = new Button
                {
                    Text = x.Button.Text,
                    Left = x.Button.Left,
                    Top = x.Button.Top,
                    Width = x.Button.Width,
                    Height = x.Button.Height,
                    Name = x.Button.Name
                };
                Timer dt = new Timer
                {
                    Interval = x.Timer.Interval,
                    Enabled = x.Timer.Enabled
                };
                System.Windows.Forms.Label ld = new System.Windows.Forms.Label
                {
                    Text = x.Label.Text,
                    Left = x.Label.Left,
                    Top = x.Label.Top,
                    Width = x.Label.Width,
                    Height = x.Label.Height,
                    Name = x.Label.Name
                };
                System.Windows.Forms.Label ld2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label
                {
                    Text = x.Label2.Text,
                    Left = x.Label2.Left,
                    Top = x.Label2.Top,
                    Width = x.Label2.Width,
                    Height = x.Label2.Height,
                    Name = x.Label2.Name
                };
                newListStore.Add(new Store(dt, pbd, bd, x.BaseMoney, x.BaseCost, x.BaseInterval, ld, ld2, game, x.IsBought)
                {
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Interval = x.Interval,
                    Num_Upgrades = x.Num_Upgrades,
                    BaseCost = x.BaseCost,
                    BaseMoney = x.BaseMoney,
                    MoneyMaking = x.MoneyMaking,
                    BaseInterval = x.BaseInterval,
                    CostOfUpgrade = x.CostOfUpgrade,
                    IntervalReducer = x.IntervalReducer,
                    EarnMultiplier = x.EarnMultiplier,
                    Clicked = x.Clicked,
                    IsBought = x.IsBought,
                    hasManager = x.hasManager,
                    game = game
                });
            });
            game.Stores = newListStore;
            game.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("1");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        game = new Game();
        AddStores();
        Serialize();
    }
}
```

What I serialize
[image: What I serialize]
The file that contains the serialization data
[image: serialization data]
What I get when I deserialize
[image: What I get when I deserialize]

Where i'm doing wrong. Seems like everything should be fine i quess the problem is on what info to fill in which control in deserialization.
[Github-Code](https://github.com/malle2002/ProjectVP)